# Error: Incompatible String Types: Unexpected return value - This is the error of my code when I return a string

Tags: java

Hello I am having trouble figuring out how to debug the error in this code. Someone please help. The return statement is returning the error of incompatible types. What do I do to fix this? Thank You!

```
public class Ex7_19 {
  public static void isSorted(int[] list) {
    String s = "The list is sorted";
    String nS = "The list is not sorted.";
    System.out.print("The list has ");
    System.out.print(list.length);
    System.out.print(" integers ");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < (list.length - 1); i++) {
      if (list[i] > list[i + 1]) {
        return nS;
      }
    }
    return s;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("#1");
    isSorted(new int[]{4,7, 19, 21, 44, 98, 101});

    System.out.println("\n#2");
    isSorted(new int[]{4,7, 54, 15, 19, 21, 44, 98, 101});

    System.out.println("\n#3");
    isSorted(new int[]{-2, 0, 3});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method:

```
public static void isSorted(int[] list) {
```

... returns void (nothing), but you are trying to return a String.

From the rest of your code, it looks like you intended to print the string and return out of the method. For example:

```
public static void isSorted(int[] list) {
    String s = "The list is sorted";
    String nS = "The list is not sorted.";
    System.out.print("The list has ");
    System.out.print(list.length);
    System.out.print(" integers ");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < (list.length - 1); i++) {
        if (list[i] > list[i + 1]) {
            System.out.println(nS);    // changed here
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(s);             // and changed here
    // no return required here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method cannot return anything since its return type is void.

change void to String to return a value.

```
public static String isSorted(int[] list) {
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the return type of **isSorted** method to **String**.
2. and print the return type in your main method.

Check the below code

```
public class Ex7_19 {
      public static String isSorted(int[] list) {
        String s = "The list is sorted";
        String nS = "The list is not sorted.";
        System.out.print("The list has ");
        System.out.print(list.length);
        System.out.print(" integers ");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
          System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < (list.length - 1); i++) {
          if (list[i] > list[i + 1]) {
            return nS;
          }
        }
        return s;
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("#1");
        System.out.println(isSorted(new int[]{4,7, 19, 21, 44, 98, 101}));

        System.out.println("\n#2");
        System.out.println(isSorted(new int[]{4,7, 54, 15, 19, 21, 44, 98, 101}));

        System.out.println("\n#3");
        System.out.println(isSorted(new int[]{-2, 0, 3}));
      }
    }
```